# Can a PyCharm IDE put a space before and after keyword arguments, parenthesis, and operators like in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pycharm

In Eclipse using PyDev I can set preferences in PyDev editor to add spaces before and after assign keyword arguments, parenthesis, and operators on save.
Example:

```
def create_socket(HOST):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST,80))
    return sock
```

After Ctrl + S code looks like:

```
def create_socket( HOST ):
    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
    sock.connect( ( HOST, 80 ) )
    return sock
```

Can PyCharm do the same?

Comment: I would point out that this is partially contrary to [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coding style is supported in PyCharm and can be enabled in Settings | Code Style | Python | Spaces | Within | Method call parentheses.

Reformat on save is not supported and not planned, because when working with PyCharm, files are saved automatically and it doesn't make much sense to make the Save action a trigger for some other behavior. You can assign the Ctrl-S shortcut to the Reformat action if you like, or enable "reformat before commit" in the commit dialog.